# Classify / Cluster Products as Fragile / Non-Fragile

Tags: nlp, text-classification

I have a bunch of products and its data description. I don't have the labels for the products. I want to develop an algorithm to classify/cluster the products as Fragile / Non-Fragile.

This is an example of the data:

[image]

Can anyone suggest me some research papers or some ideas that I can implement? My idea is to take some particular keywords and use them to classify but I cannot find a way to do it.

Comment: don't choose the words by yourself, the NN (if you will use that) will figure it out by yourself... what you have to do, is to label manually if those descriptions represent a fragile (or not) package, and then feed the NN with the text (there are several ways to do text base NN) and with time and data it will learn

Comment: but the text should be obv be meaningful, however a binary classification should not required too much data (i would say that depending on how good the model is, you might need some thousands of examples)... also you can try to use Unsupervised leaning to avoid having to label everything, but to first group them and then use  a NN to classify

Comment: first page that i've found is this https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2018/04/a-comprehensive-guide-to-understand-and-implement-text-classification-in-python/

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia in this article, the dataset has labels while I don't have labels.

Comment: How do you think that a computer can learn? you have to tell it X times what it's fragile and what is not... therefore, you need to label at least some of your data, for sure, there is not such algorithm/model that will learn classification without labeled data

Comment: To complement what Alberto said, your idea to pick particular keywords means that you would implement the rules manually (as opposed to training a ML model). It can make sense in some cases, but in general it's not as efficient as training a model from labelled examples.